# Android Studio : When ever i run my app, it says Unfortunately app has stopped

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

I am trying to get an input from user and then covert it into double and divide it by 1000 and then set the value in a textview but i while running the app, the app closes and says Unfortunately the app has stopped. 
Here's my MainActivity.java file :

```
package com.blogspot.techtutorialsajen.androiddevelopmentpractice;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private Button btn1;
private EditText get;
private TextView result;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    get = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.get);

    final double value = Double.parseDouble(get.getText().toString()) / 1000;

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            result.setText(String.valueOf(value));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And My activity_main.xml file :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/get"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:hint="@string/enter_a_number"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:text="@string/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/result"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20pt"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: share your crash log with question

Comment: Post here Error log

Comment: TextView need String to show the value. If you directly set the double value to TextView than it crashes the App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Your app is crashes because of  `java.lang.RuntimeException:java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""` 
that means you are trying to convert `empty string` to `Double`.

So, Because the `EditText` is empty your app is crashes and I have re-write your code so that you can `copy-paste`.

Here is your `MainActivity.Java`

```
package com.blogspot.techtutorialsajen.androiddevelopmentpractice;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private Button btn1;
private EditText get;
private TextView result;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
    get = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.get);
 btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (get.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity .this, "Please input something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    final double value = Double.parseDouble(get.getText().toString()) / 1000;
                    result.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

and here is your `activity_main.XML`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/get"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:hint="@string/enter_a_number"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:text="@string/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/result"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="28dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20pt"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have added  `android:inputType="number"` property to your `EditText` so that, now on, it will only take `Number` from the user.

Answer (score 0):

From your xml file and activity code, it clearly says your ***`edittext is empty`*** while launching app.

And you are using this code in `oncreate()`

```
final double value = Double.parseDouble(get.getText().toString()) / 1000;
```

which throws **`java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String`**

You can change your code like,

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(!get.getText().toString().isEmpty)
           final double value = Double.parseDouble(get.getText().toString()) / 1000;
           result.setText(String.valueOf(value));

        }
    });
}
```